# Connecting objects with a line in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a list of json objects.

```
var Planets = [
            {name:"maths", percComp: "2", preReq: "english"},
            {name:"english", percComp: "20", preReq: "geog"},
            {name:"geog", percComp: "57", preReq: "maths"}          
        ];
```

These objects are planets that i will add to a universe. They are school subjects

I also have a planet class

```
function Planet(planet, index)
    {
        this.name = planet.name;
        this.percComp = planet.percComp;
        this.preReq = planet.preReq;
        CreatePlanet(this, index);
        this.line = paper.path('');

        function RedrawLine(planetFrom, planetTo, strokeWidth)
        {
            line.attr({
                path:"M" + planetFrom.attrs.cx + "," + planetFrom.attrs.cy + "L"+ planetTo.attrs.cx + "," + planetTo.attrs.cy,
                "stroke-width": strokeWidth
            }); 
        }

        function CreatePlanet(planet)
        {
            var planetName = planet.name;
            planetName = paper.circle(200 * index, 100, 80/index);
            planetName.attr({ 
                fill:'red',
                stroke: '#3b4449',
                'stroke-width': 6               
            });

            SetGlow(30, true, 0, 0, 'grey', planetName)
            SetHover(planetName);
        }

        function SetHover(planet)
        {
            var radius = planet.attrs.r;
            planet.mouseover(function(){
                this.animate({ r: radius * 1.3}, 150)
            }).mouseout(function(){
                this.animate({ r: radius}, 150)
            })
        }

        function SetGlow(width, fill, offSetx, offsety, color, planet)
        {
            planet.glow({
                width: 30,
                fill: true,
                offsetx: 0,
                offsety: 0,
                color: 'grey'
            });
        }

    }
```

The code to initiate the program is

```
var element = document.getElementById('Main-Content')
var paper = new Raphael(element, 1000, 1000);


    window.onload = function()
    {

        var planetsSet = paper.set();

        var index = 1;
        $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(Planets))).each(function(){
            var planet = new Planet(this, index);
            planetsSet.push(planet);
            index++;
        });

        for (i=0; i<planetsSet.length; i++)
        {
            var planetTo = planetsSet[i];
                            // This is a test to see if RedrawLine works
                            var planeFrom = planetsFrom[i+1];
            planetTo.RedrawLine(planetTo, planeFrom, 30)
            var preReq = this.preReq;          
        }
    }
```

The code populates the screen with 3 planets. I am trying to connect these with a line. The line will connect a planet with its pre requisite that is declared in the json object. So maths has a pre requisite english, and english has a pre requisite geog. I have a function in the Planet class that will draw the line, but I cant access the objects after they have been drawn.

Is this a problem with Raphael or can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several errors in your approach:

- Paper.set is not `Array`, use `Array` for such purpse
- you messed scopes, pass `paper` to your object constructor
- public methods should be declared at  least as `this.method` not just `function method()`
- keep a public properties of your planet in `this.property` object or at least not call this.planet  as PlanetName.
- you forget to use this.line in your redraw method

little code to fill the void:

```
var planetsSet = [];
```

[working sample](http://jsbin.com/adapug/4)

*homework:*

Remove `planetFrom` from `RedrawLine` method parameters, to be possible call this method as
`PlanetFrom.RedrawLine(planetTo);`